# how can I dynamically add ondrag event in a created span

Tags: javascript

New to javascript, sorry my English is bad.

I call `getpb()` from HTML, this is what I want

`<span id="drag1" title="teeth" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragThis(event)">my teeth</span>`

This is what I have, **I access array** , I set the for loop to 10 instead of array length

```
function getpb(){
    j=1;
    var pbdiv = document.getElementById("pickBox");
    for (var i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        var elem = document.createElement("span");
        document.getElementById("pickBox").appendChild.elem;
        elem.id = [j];
        elem.title = "teeth";
        elem.draggable = "true"; 
        elem.ondrag ? does not work
        elem.innerHTML = "my teeth";
        console.log(elem);
        pbdiv.appendChild(elem);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of adding `onDragStart` on `span` add it to `parentElement` and use `event.target` for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need to add `ondragstart` event there

```js
function dragThis(event){
  //TODO: Add your logic here
  console.log('dragging')
  console.log(event.target.id)
}

function getpb(){
    j=1;
    var pbdiv = document.getElementById("pickBox");
    for (var i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        var elem = document.createElement("span");
        document.getElementById("pickBox").appendChild.elem;
        elem.id = [j];
        elem.title = "teeth";
        elem.draggable = "true"; 
        elem.ondragstart = dragThis
        elem.innerHTML = "my teeth";
        pbdiv.appendChild(elem);
        i++;
        j++;
    }
}

getpb()
```

```html
<div id="pickBox">

</div>
```